# Compiling files in a directory into their own zip folder using a makefile script

Tags: bash, makefile, terminal

I am currently taking a class where we submit homework through an online tool. However, it requires submissions to be made up of individually zipped files in order to compile them properly. This is time consuming when I sometimes make multiple submissions. I am trying to write a make file script to make a zipped copy of all files within the same folder. I then want to move those zipped files to a sub directory I create afterward called zippedFiles. This is what I have so far. The for loop line works when I run it directly in terminal but has the following error when I run make zip I get the following error: zip error: Nothing to do! (.zip) I am new to learning bash and make files and have been unable to research a solution on my own.

```
zip:
    rm -f ./*zip    #remove any extra zip copies.
    rm -rf zippedFiles #delete old zippedFiles
    for i in *; do zip $i.zip $i; done #zip each file ***not working
    mkdir zippedFiles       #remake new zippedFiles directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In makefiles, you must use twice the `$` to reference to a variable from the for loop.

`for i in *; do zip $$i.zip $$i; done`

Comment: To expand on this, make will see `$i`, assume it's a make variable, and expand it (to blank, as it's not set), before passing the string `for i in *; do zip .zip ; done` to the shell.   If you use `$$`, make expands this to `$` before passing to the shell.